# How to match only that phrase which ends on ";" and has one pair of brackets?

Tags: regex

I have somethink like that:

```
RuleFor(x =>x.xd != null).NotEmpty(); // I dont want to match this

RuleFor(x =>x.xd != null);            // I want to match only this, independently of that, what is in brackets
```

Comment: @PM77-1: It returns: "Your message has been deleted".

Comment: Does this work: https://regex101.com/r/Wfy52M/1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^(?!.*\(.*\).*\(.*\)).*;$
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/XAPJUe/1)

---

- `(?!.*\(.*\).*\(.*\))` - don't match string where two `(.*)` are found
- `.*;$` - match all where the last character is `;`

Comment: That's that ! Could You please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: (?!.*\(.*\).*\(.*\)) - don't match string where two (.*) are found - could You please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: @ruddnisrus `(?! ... )` is `negative lookahead`, we have it at the beginning of the regex, so first thing we do we check the whole string for the pattern inside `.*\(.*\).*\(.*\)`. If this pattern is found, we don't continue further.

Comment: Could You explain more this string pattern?

Comment: @ruddnisrus `.` - any character, `*` - any amount of this character. So `.*\(.*\).*\(.*\)` means literally: `any char/any amount, (, any string/any amount, ), any char/any amount, (, any char/any amount, )`